# Styling CSS to give the feel of a native app

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, jsfiddle

I would like my unordered list that is animated with jquerys accordion feature to take up the whole width and height the screen to give the feel of a native mobile application. One of the list elements will be dropped down at all times.

Here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/Rm66M/5/

How can this be done by strictly manipulating the CSS?

The animation is done to the div layer with id = celebs, #celebs
I have added

```
    body, celebs, and html styling to remove all margins and padding
```

How do I take up exactly the full height of my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the *feel* you're looking for, but if you want your sections to take up 100% of your windows height:

```
html, body, #celebs, #accordion, li.active {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind that that will make the active li take up the full height of the window. If you want it to "take up whatever vertical space is remaining after show the other *closed* sections", you'll need to do a little math. (window height - other li's combined height = left over for sizing the active li).

If you want, you can also simply try using jQueryUI's accordion with `heightStyle: "fill"` (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace)